# Wordpress post views count twice

Tags: wordpress, post, view, count

I created post view feature. But i have a problem. My function counts twice per page refresh. 0,2,4,6,8... thank you in advance.

**My functions.php**

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count;
}

function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}


add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = 'Views';
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
 if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}
```

**My single.php:**

```
get_header();
if(function_exists('getPostViews')) { echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); }

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if(function_exists('setPostViews')) { setPostViews(get_the_ID()); }      

the_content(); 

endwhile;

get_footer();
```

I think my single.php loops twice. My be it helps you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your functions.php to remove issues with prefetching adding extra views

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Also make sure this line does not exist in your `header.php` Because no path was set, Chrome would actually try to hit the same page a second time in order to get the shortcut icon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
```

---

**Another solution**

reset all your queries just at the point where those looping queries end up,with this tag wp_reset_query();

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried both but still not works. I created custom css like this:
    wp_add_inline_style( $handle, $custom_css  ); 
This line is causing to error.

Comment: reset all your queries just at the point where those looping queries end up,with this tag wp_reset_query();